# Passing values from from Servlet to JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

I am attempting to pass certain values from my servlet to the JSP page and add the values which have been passed to the  tag, reading many posts I've got the following code.

1. Use input tage to select files
2. Verify files uploaded
3. invoke upload.java to save uploaded files in WEB-INF
4. of the uploaded file a selected file is saved as my.txt
5. Use buffers to read contents of the file and save them to a variable
6. passing this to the JSP page

upload.java

After uploading the files,

```
response.setContentType("text/html");
String LINE = "<br>";
String filename = "/WEB-INF/my.txt";
fileTxt = "";
ServletContext context = getServletContext();
InputStream is = context.getResourceAsStream(filename);
if (is != null) {
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();
String text = "";
while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
fileTxt = text + LINE;
}
request.setAttribute("File_Text", fileTxt);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("mypage.jsp");
rd.forward(request, response);

}
```

mypage.jsp

```
<div id="editor"></div>

<form method="post" name="myform" action="upload" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="position: absolute; right: -5%; top: 2%;">
 Left File :     <input type="file" name="dataFile1" id="fileChooser1" /><br><br>
 Right File : <input type="file" name="dataFile2" id="fileChooser2" /><br><br>
 Config File :<input type="file" name="dataFile3" id="fileChooser3" /><br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="ValidateFile()">Click to Upload files</button>
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function ValidateFile()
{
var FileName1 = document.getElementById('fileChooser1').value;
var FileName2 = document.getElementById('fileChooser2').value;
var FileName3 = document.getElementById('fileChooser3').value;

if(FileName1.length == 0 && FileName2.length == 0 && FileName3.length == 0)
{
    alert("No files have been selected to upload"); 
}

else
{
if(FileName1 == FileName3 ||  FileName2 == FileName3)
    {
        alert("Configuration file should not be same as left or right files. Please check your uploads");
    }
else
    {
        document.myform.submit();
    }

var filecontent =   ${File_Text};
var divv = document.getElementById("editor");
divv.innerHTML = filecontent;

}
}
</script>
```

Now, after doing all this when I click my upload button, it is just not working and the click is not at all being recognized but when I remove the file accessing code the button works fine..

1. why is this happening? what to do?
2. Is this the right way to accessing values of servlet in JSP?

======================================EDIT=======================================

Just to clarify things further,

1. User uploads a file
2. That file is saved as my.txt
3. I am opening this file, reading its contents
4. adding those contents to my ACE editor in

Comment: Its a little unclear what you want. Do you want to upload file from desktop to server? Again you want to show the file contents as text in browser page? Is there any other parameters or data that you want to display on the page? Mention the functionality that you are trying to achieve.

Comment: why you are using the printwriter while you are forwarding the request to jsp via request dispatcher?

Comment: Hey, I've just added a clarification

Comment: I've used print writer only to check it was working...

Comment: as i understand filetext  is a servlet variable which will be created once u submit input files .. then at client level var filecontent =   ${File_Text}; will be nothing. as its set value before submit.

Comment: First of all there is no use of var filecontent =   ${File_Text}.. and you are telling it's not working with file accessing code, can you see the console is there any error?

Comment: I'm sorry @Neha I didn't get you..

Comment: hey @Deepak213 I am using it to get contents of the file that has been read in upload.java

Comment: But it's setting the value of filecontent var at the time when you are clicking the upload button and that time it's value is null.

Comment: See as per my understanding .. at upload button u were checking those file input name validation and submit data (form submit).. once its submit and down u using the file_text string which is server side and its blank .. bcaz jsp/servlet variable replace content first and later js part execute.

Comment: Oh okay. So how do you suggest me to approach my problem? @Deepak213

Comment: Okay @Neha..Sounds right but how do I correct this?

Comment: Use ajax to call ur servlet and fill server return content in div. if u want everything in same page (without changing page).

Comment: @Neha Will check that out. Using ajax, I've never done that.

Comment: Yeah ajax is good solution to find the response without changing the control of current page.

Comment: Can anyone tell me how to do it in ajax?

Comment: One more thing, are you able to see the content of file in console by printwriter?

Comment: Yes I 'was' able to see content in Print writer but not after adding $File_Text commands I am not even able to click the button!

Comment: use the inspect debugger in browser to check what error its shows. and are u aware of jquery..as they have easy methods of ajax.

Comment: Hey why are you using javascript to show the message.

Comment: Use <div id="editor">${File_Text}</div>

Comment: I'll just try it out will let you know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No change in Upload.java

```
 <div id="editor">${File_Text}</div>

<form method="post" name="myform" action="upload" target="_blank" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="position: absolute; right: -5%; top: 2%;">
 Left File :     <input type="file" name="dataFile1" id="fileChooser1" /><br><br>
 Right File : <input type="file" name="dataFile2" id="fileChooser2" /><br><br>
 Config File :<input type="file" name="dataFile3" id="fileChooser3" /><br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="ValidateFile()">Click to Upload files</button>
</form>
<script type='text/javascript'>

function ValidateFile()
{
var FileName1 = document.getElementById('fileChooser1').value;
var FileName2 = document.getElementById('fileChooser2').value;
var FileName3 = document.getElementById('fileChooser3').value;

if(FileName1.length == 0 && FileName2.length == 0 && FileName3.length == 0)
{
    alert("No files have been selected to upload"); 
}

else
{
if(FileName1 == FileName3 ||  FileName2 == FileName3)
    {
        alert("Configuration file should not be same as left or right files. Please check your uploads");
    }
else
    {
        document.myform.submit();
    {

}
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hey @Deepak213 thanks for your answer. I'll try this out and will let you know.

Comment: Hey deepak this works but all the text is being printed in the same line...I'd be glad I you could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
fileTxt = text + LINE;
}
request.setAttribute("File_Text", fileTxt);
RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("mypage.jsp");    
rd.forward(request, response);
```

Comment: @Zedai What has to be in while loop?